# How to make a type out of inherited custom classes c++

Tags: c++, templates, inventory

I am trying to build my first game in c++ and I am attempting to make an `Inventory` system that will allow me to manage and arrange different `Item` data types within an `Inventory` container type. In the code below I only have the class declarations made up but I wanted to know how to make the "Item" class that I have made hold a data type of any of the different inherited items such as the `Weapon`, `Apparel`, and `Aid` categories. Would it be as simple as using a `template` parameter? If so then my question is how does something like a `Constructor` understand what to do in each instance of creating an item? The `default Constructor` may have to be something like a basic weapon that I decide to set up, correct? If anyone has any advice or links to provide that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

ITEM.H:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <iostream>

/*************************************************
* ITEM CLASS
* *This class is the type of data to be put into
*  the Inventory Container class.
**************************************************/
class Item
{
public:

private:

};

/*************************************************
* WEAPON CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies a
*  weapon item that can be in an Inventory.
**************************************************/
class Weapon : public Item
{
public:

private:

};

/*************************************************
* APPAREL CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies an
*  apparel item that can be in an Inventory.
**************************************************/
class Apparel : public Item
{
public:

private:

};

/*************************************************
* AID CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies an
*  Aid item that can be in an Inventory.
**************************************************/
class Aid : public Item
{
public:

private:

};

#endif //ITEM_H
```

EDIT:

Here is what I have as of now:

```
/*************************************************
* ITEM CLASS
* *This class is the type of data to be put into
*  the Inventory Container class.
**************************************************/
template <class T>
class Item
{
public:


private:
    T item_type;         //i.e. Weapon, Apparel, Aid, etc...

};

/*****************************************************************
* ITEM : WEAPON 
* *Below is the code for all the different Weapon classes.
******************************************************************/

/*************************************************
* WEAPON CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies a
*  weapon item that can be in an Inventory.
**************************************************/
template <class T>
class Weapon : public Item
{
public:

private:
    T weapon_type;      //i.e. Melee, Ranged, etc...
};

/*************************************************
* MELEE CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies a
*  melee item that will be used as a weapon.
**************************************************/
template <class T>
class Melee : public Weapon
{
public:

private:

};

/*************************************************
* RANGED CLASS
* *This class is a type of Item that classifies a
*  ranged item that will be used as a weapon.
**************************************************/
template <class T>
class Ranged : public Weapon
{
public:

private:

};
```

ANOTHER EDIT:
Here is the newest code:

```
/*************************************************
* ITEM CLASS
* *This class is the type of data to be put into
*  the Inventory Container class.
**************************************************/
template <class T>
class Item
{
public:


protected:
    T item_type;         //i.e. Weapon, Apparel, Aid, etc...

};

/*****************************************************************
* ITEM : WEAPON 
* *Below is the code for all the different Weapon classes.
******************************************************************/

//WEAPON CLASS
template <class T>
class Weapon : public Item
{
public:

protected:
    T weapon_type;      //i.e. Melee, Ranged, etc...
};

//MELEE CLASS
template <class T>
class Melee : public Weapon
{
public:

protected:
    T melee_type;      //i.e. Blade, Blunt, Fist, etc...

};

//BLADE CLASS
template <class T>
class Blade : public Melee
{
public:

protected:
    T blade_type;      //i.e. Dagger, Sword, etc...
};

//DAGGER CLASS
template <class T>
class Dagger : public Blade
{
public:
    //Default Constructor...the only Constructor
    Dagger() : damage(1), weight(0.5) { }

    //getters
    std::string getType() const { return "Dagger"; }

protected:
    int   damage;      //amount of damage it can inflict
    float weight;      //weight of the dagger
};
```

Comment: I'm not talking about for the Inventory class. I mean for the member variable in the Item class.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to figure out how to set the member variable in `Item` so that it can be any of the categories like Weapon, apparel, etc. but I am not sure if a template will be the best for it. But I don't know of any other way to handle something like that either.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes. That is what I am getting at.

Comment: Should the template's that I put have different letters as I go down the inheritance list? So like Item -> Weapon -> Melee -> Sword... Should each of them have a different template parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to define your types as `enum`s.

```cpp
enum ITEM_TYPE { IT_WEAPON, IT_END };
enum WEAPON_TYPE { WT_MELEE, WT_RANGED, WT_END };

class Item {
public:
    Item(ITEM_TYPE type) : item_type(type) {}
protected:
    ITEM_TYPE item_type;
};

class Weapon : public Item {
public:
    Weapon(WEAPON_TYPE type) : Item(IT_WEAPON), weapon_type(type) {}
protected:
    WEAPON_TYPE weapon_type;
};

class MeleeWeapon : public Weapon {
public:
    MeleeWeapon() : Weapon(WT_MELEE) {}
};

class RangedWeapon : public Weapon {
public:
    RangedWeapon() : Weapon(WT_RANGED) {}
};
```

Comment: So would I want to make the member variables private or protected? Why?

Comment: `protected` members are only accessible by the `class` and any derived `class`es. `private` members are only accessible by the `class`. In this case, `item_type` can be accessed by `Item`, `Weapon`, `MeleeWeapon`, `RangedWeapon`. But if it was `private`, it can only be accessed by `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't need to store a type (type in the C++ language sense), use virtual functions to achieve what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Item
{
public:
     virtual const char* type() const = 0;
};

class Weapon : public Item
{
public:
      const char* type() const override { return "Weapon"; }
};

class Ranged : public Weapon
{
public:
    const char* type() const override { return "Ranged"; }
};

class Melee : public Weapon
{
public:
    const char* type() const override { return "Melee"; }
};

class Apparel : public Item
{
public:
    const char* type() const override { return "Apparel"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;

    items.emplace_back(new Apparel());
    items.emplace_back(new Ranged());
    items.emplace_back(new Melee());

    std::cout << "Inventory Types:\n";
    for (const auto& it: items)
        std::cout << it->type() << '\n';
}
```

See http://cpp.sh/6cjlt

Comment: I don't know if this would work because I want to get various variables and functions and types for each of the different items that can be made.